# appium: how to push file

Tags: python, android, appium

I tried to push file into my device using `appium`.

When I see my device in my windows machine, this is the toor path:

```
This PC\P00A\Internal shared storage
```

So if I want to move this file from my machine:

```
C:\file.txt
```

I tried using this command:

```
self.driver.push_file('C:\file.txt', android_path)
```

But what path should I put instead of `android_path` ? I am trying to write to  `sdcard`.

Comment: /sdcard/file.txt should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of parameters is incorrect, according to [Push File command documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/index.html) it should be:

```
driver.push_file("/sdcard/file.txt","c:/file.txt")
                   #remote path      local path
```

You might also be interested in [Run Command (adb)](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=52593322) extension which allows executing arbitrary [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) commands like:

```
seetest.run("adb push c:/file.txt /sdcard/file.txt");
```